# Is it possible to disable video feeds on Discord for Android?

Tags: discord

When doing a video call via Discord, one can turn off each friend's video feed. That is, if one is using the desktop client. It is possible on the desktop, but, curiously, not trivial in the metered connection of the cellphone...

I tried: long-pressing the person, looking into video configurations, searching both in search.brave.com and Google, and found no solution.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: It seems like it not yet possible. [Many users have asked about it on Discord support](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360067741272-please-add-disable-video-to-mobile-context-menu) for more than a year now, but the feature has not yet been implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, not possible**

**Source**

My email to support@discordapp.com asking

> When doing a video call , one can turn off each friend's video feed (without affecting audio) . That is, if one is using the desktop client, but not on Android. On Android, Possible, not possible? Planned for future or not? Steps if possible please

Their reply (request # (17987066) assigned)

> Sadly, we don't have any option to turn off the video feed on mobile devices. Unfortunately, we also don't have any timeframe if this feature will be implemented on all mobile devices. 
> If you would like to see changes to these systems in the future, then you can definitely create or vote up the suggestions at [feedback.discord.com](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/topics). It would really help us out if you upvote the idea since feedback contributes greatly to our decision-making of which features and fixes to implement in the future based on what our community wants.
> I'm so sorry again that we don't have a current solution for you at this time, but I like to think that anything is possible in the future.
> Please let me know if you have any other questions!
> Cheers,
> Daniel R

[image]

(Click to enlarge)

As pointed out in [comments](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/242199/is-it-possible-to-disable-video-feeds-on-discord-for-android#comment323434_242199), the fact that is open for so long is another indicator